# Hibernate JPA "Associated class not found" using another Entity as Key and Embeddable as Value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-Boot-Web 2.3.6.RELEASE with the JPA Starter and Postgres.

On startup, I get the following Hibernate-Exception:

```
2021-01-24 22:53:23.606 ERROR 2026 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectEntityRepository' defined in io.share.backend.repository.ObjectEntityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: io.share.backend.repository.model.EntityShare$EntityShareEntry
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at io.share.backend.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: io.share.backend.repository.model.EntityShare$EntityShareEntry
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: io.share.backend.repository.model.EntityShare$EntityShareEntry
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.bindKeyFromAssociationTable(MapBinder.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.access$000(MapBinder.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

The relevant part of my schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "encryption_key" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "raw" BYTEA NOT NULL,
    "algorithm" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("raw")
) ;

CREATE TABLE "account" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "issuer" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "registration_time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "display_name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "storage_root" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "encryption_key_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("issuer", "name"),
    UNIQUE ("storage_root"),
    UNIQUE ("encryption_key_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("encryption_key_id") REFERENCES "encryption_key" ("id")
) ;

CREATE TABLE "entity" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "owner_account_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    "creation_time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("owner_account_id") REFERENCES "account" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;

CREATE TABLE "entity_tag" (
    "entity_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "key" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "value" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("entity_id", "key"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("entity_id") REFERENCES "entity" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;

CREATE TABLE "entity_share" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "entity_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "open_entry_count" INT NOT NULL,
    "permission_flags" INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("entity_id") REFERENCES "entity" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;

CREATE TABLE "entity_share_entry" (
    "entity_share_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "entry_account_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "entry_time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("entity_share_id", "entry_account_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("entity_share_id") REFERENCES "entity_share" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ("entry_account_id") REFERENCES "account" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;
```

And my Entity-Classes:

*EncryptionKey*

```java
package io.share.backend.repository.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "encryption_key")
public class EncryptionKey implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "encryption_key_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "encryption_key_id_seq", sequenceName = "encryption_key_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "raw")
    private byte[] raw;

    @Column(name = "algorithm")
    private String algorithm;
}
```

*Account*

```java
package io.share.backend.repository.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_id_seq", sequenceName = "account_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "issuer")
    private String issuer;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "registration_time")
    private Instant registrationTime;

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name = "storage_root")
    private String storageRoot;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "encryption_key_id", nullable = false)
    private EncryptionKey encryptionKey;
}
```

*BaseEntity*

```java
package io.share.backend.repository.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "entity_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "entity_id_seq", sequenceName = "entity_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_account_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Account ownerAccount;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Instant creationTime;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Type type;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "entity_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "key")
    @Column(name = "value")
    private Map<String, String> tags;

    public enum Type {

        FOLDER,
        OBJECT,
        VIEW,
        VIEW_EXPORT
    }
}
```

*EntityShare*

```java
package io.share.backend.repository.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_share")
public class EntityShare {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "entity_share_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "entity_share_id_seq", sequenceName = "entity_share_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private BaseEntity entity;

    @Column(name = "open_entry_count")
    private int openEntryCount;

    @Column(name = "permission_flags")
    private int permissionFlags;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "entity_share_entry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_share_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @MapKey(name = "entry_account_id")
    private Map<Account, EntityShareEntry> entries;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class EntityShareEntry {

        @Column(name = "entry_time")
        private Instant entryTime;
    }
}
```

When changing my *EntityShare*-Entity to:

```java
package io.share.backend.repository.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_share")
public class EntityShare {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "entity_share_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "entity_share_id_seq", sequenceName = "entity_share_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private BaseEntity entity;

    @Column(name = "open_entry_count")
    private int openEntryCount;

    @Column(name = "permission_flags")
    private int permissionFlags;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "entity_share_entry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_share_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "entry_account_id")
    @Column(name = "entry_time")
    private Map<Long, Instant> entries;
}
```

It seems to work, but I would like to have (if possible) the actual Account as the key and also have the opportunity to add more fields and not just having the entry_time as a value in the future.

Is this possible with an Map-Reference like I have now? If yes, how? If not, how could I possibly represent this in another way using JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to correct this:

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "entity_share_entry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_share_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@MapKey(name = "entry_account_id")
private Map<Account, EntityShareEntry> entries;
```

to this:

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "entity_share_entry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_share_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "entry_account_id")
private Map<Account, EntityShareEntry> entries;
```

Please also note that Embeddable and Entity classes *must be a top-level classes* (see sections 2.5 and 2.1 of JPA spec)